# What is the legality of Pokemon showdown?

Tags: pokemon-series, legal

http://pokemonshowdown.com has been around for a while, and it is still up and running today. Is it because it is legal to play there? Or are there other factors in play?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking about the legality of a certain game.  We are not lawyers, and are not equipped to answer questions of what is and isn't legal.

Answer (score 5):

Pokemon Showdown uses images, sprites, music and other Intellectual Property (IP) of Gamefreak, Nintendo & The Pokemon Company. It is most likely breaching some of Nintendo's copyright.

Note that Showdown and other sites don't need to be making money in order to be infringing. Copyright infringement occurs *regardless* of whether there is profit being made. Usually, the 'takedowns' people hear about are because the copyright holder believes that the infringing material is taking away from *their* profits. If Showdown was providing enough of an incentive to play on their service that people *stopped buying the actual games*, it's likely that Nintendo would act on this.

Note that the inaction on Nintendo/Gamefreak's behalf so far does not constitute their blessing. At any point they can choose whether to act on a case of copyright infringement. If they wanted, they could take down or severely limit the capabilities of fan sites like Pokemon Showdown, Serebii, Bulbapedia etc for using their copyrighted materials.

So why don't they just issue takedowns on everything? *It's bad for business*. There is a beneficial effect of having fans build sites, curate libraries of resources and constantly talk about and consume your content. **It's free marketing.** Whether a copyright holder chooses to exercise their right is essentially a cost/benefit analysis.

In conclusion, Showdown most likely infringes on Nintendo's copyright. However, as of writing, Nintendo has not *acted* on these potential infringements. While this can change at any point, there is no danger to using the services while they are available.

<sub>Also, show your support to Nintendo/Gamefreak and buy the actual Pokemon Games! :)</sub>

Comment: Hmm I'm more interested in the ethics of the situation vs being sued, but I think your answer provides sufficient information to inform an ethical stance.

Comment: "If they wanted, they could take down or severely limit the capabilities of fan sites like Pokemon Showdown, Serebii, Bulbapedia etc for using their copyrighted materials." I'm not too familiar with all of these, but isn't Bulbapedia just a wiki? Documentation of freely available information isn't copyright infringement, especially when they make no attempt to obfuscate the copyright ownership. The issue with Pokemon Showdown would be its attempt to imitate the Pokemon games outright, not with the fact that they display Pokemon sprites (although that adds to the issue).

Comment: @AverageUnknown - Bulbapedia uses images, sprites and animations extracted from game files. Whilst most of the information on Bulbapedia is probably fine, those may be considered infringing. Of course, one could argue fair use as an educational tool, so there is a case on either side there. The point is, none of this has seen a courtroom, so it's just speculation.

Comment: By that logic Let's Play videos are also infringement--which to be fair has been a major subject of great contention lately (see TotalBiscuit's videos on Youtube). I think it's still a pretty grey area of copyright law right now, due to the nature of video games as an art.

Comment: I think calling it fair use under education is a stretch, but maybe.

Comment: @AverageUnknown - either way, I hope we never have to find out :-)